# Hide one WCF service in wsdl

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have my own wsdl with few methods.
They are visible in e.g. SoapUI.
I want to implement new service, but I want to hide it from wsdl, but I want to call it.

Is that possible?

Comment: Are you talking about a new service contract? Or just a new operation on your existing service?

Comment: New service contract. Just for development purpose. Production environments shouldn't see this service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. Just tell WCF you do not want to expose metadata in the service configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="MyService">
      <endpoint address="http://MyService:8888" binding="wsSomeBinding" contract="IMyServiceContract" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```